# Excel Calculate a running average on filtered data with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to calculate a running average on a filtered data table. All other posts online use Sumproduct(Subtotal) on the entire range but do not calculate a row by row running average

**I am stuck on how to calculate columns C and D.**

If **column B (Score)** > 0, I want to sum and average it under **column C (Average Win)**

If **column B (Score)** < 0, I want to sum and average it under **column D (Average Loss)**

The table is filterable by **column A (Type)** and the results should look as follows

[image]

---

---

Progress so far:

I have figured out how to calculate a Cumulative score based on filtered data. However this does not fully solve my problem. I appreciate any help!

> =SUBTOTAL(3,B3)*SUBTOTAL(9,B$3:B3)

**SUBTOTAL(3,B3)** checks if the current row is visible, **SUBTOTAL(9,B$3:b3)** sums the values.

[image]

---

---

### Final update needed

Jos - Thank you for your detailed explanation on how subtotal() works. I learned a ton through your explanation and will continue to study it. This is my first time being exposed to structured referencing so some of the syntax is a bit confusing to me still

The last formula I need is a running win % column where a Win is defined by score > 0. Please see the picture below

[image]

My assumptions believe that the same formula would work, except that we average a 1 or 0 in each row instead of the [Score] column.
Using the prior solution, why can't we modify the output of your prior solution to calculate a **running win %**?

```
[...] IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Win])))),0)
```

Where [Win] is a helper column with the outputs 1 for win, 0 for loss.
This could be done by saying

```
if([@score]>0,1,0)
```

Instead of averaging out the actual @Score, this would average out a column of 1's and 0's with the desired output 0%, 50%, 66%, etc.

---

I am aware that the solution I provided does not work but I am trying to embrace the correct logic. I still struggle to understand how these structured column references are calculated on a row by row basis.
For example: `Average(If([Score]>0,[Score])`

How is this calculated on a row by row basis? When A3 does **If([Score] > 0,)**, does this equal **If({-10}>0)**? When on A4, does **If([Score]>0)** equal **If({-10,20} >0)**? Thank you for your patience and help thus far.

Comment: You nearly had it! Since you've added a helper column to determine whether a given row is a "Win" or not, you no longer need the part `IF([Score]>0` within the fomula; removing this should give you your desired results.

Comment: Regarding how, e.g., `IF([Score]>0)` is calculated row by row, it returns an array comprising the results of that expression for each row referenced. This array will be the same for every instance of the formula. It is possible to make it such that the array returned comprises a different number of elements, e.g. successively increasing by one in size as we progress down the table, though I preferred to avoid this necessity by inserting the additional clause `IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score])` to instruct the formula in each row to ignore any rows prior to that row as part of the calculation.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks again, I really appreciate everything! I understand now how the running calculation is different on each row due to the Averaging the constantly changing OFFSET(INDEX[Score]1). It is all becoming clear to me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with your result for *Average Loss* for the last row of your unfiltered table (surely -9.33...?), but try this for *Average Win*:

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX([Score],1),ROW([Score])-MIN(ROW([Score])),)),IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Score])))),0)`

Same formula for *Average Loss*, changing `[Score]>0` to `[Score]<0`.

***Explanation***:

Using the data you provided and assuming:

1. The table's top-left cell is in `A1`
2. The table is filtered on the *Type* column for "A"

In order to determine which rows are filtered, we must pass an array of range references - i.e. for each cell within a chosen column of the table - to the `SUBTOTAL` function. It's a touch unfortunate that such an array of range references can only be generated via a *[volatile](https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm#:%7E:text=A%20Volatile%20Function%20is%20one,also%20contains%20non%2Dvolatile%20functions.)* function (`INDIRECT` or `OFFSET`), but here, unless we resort to helper columns, we are left with no choice.

`INDEX([Score],1)`

simply returns a range reference to the first cell within the *Score* column. When using Excel tables, it's preferable not to write formulas which include a mixture of structured and non-structured referencing, even if that results in slightly longer expressions. So here, for example, we would not reference `A2` within the formula.

`ROW([Score])-MIN(ROW([Score]))`

generates an array of integers from 0 up to one fewer than the number of rows in the table, i.e.

`{0;1;2;3;4}`

and so

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX([Score],1),ROW([Score])-MIN(ROW([Score])),)),IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Score])))),0)`

becomes

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,{0;1;2;3;4},)),IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Score])))),0)`

`OFFSET` then generates an array of range references (though note that you will not be able to 'see' this step within the Evaluate Formula window - rather, an array of #VALUE! errors is displayed):

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,{A2;A3;A4;A5;A6}),IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Score])))),0)`

`SUBTOTAL` then determines which of these range references is filtered (note that care must be given here to the choice of first parameter), returning the relevant Boolean, so that:

`SUBTOTAL(3,{A2;A3;A4;A5;A6})`

resolves to:

`{1;1;1;0;1}`

And so we now have:

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF({1;1;1;0;1},IF([Score]>0,IF(ROW([Score])<=ROW([@Score]),[Score])))),0)`

and the rest is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you Jos, I apologize for the inaccurate data, I incorrectly hardcoded that column to demonstrate what I was looking for. Your answer works perfectly. Could you briefly explain the logic behind this solution? What is the purpose of OFFSET?

Comment: Jos, using the same logic above using [Score]>0 and [Score]<0, how could I calculate a running win %? I assume it would be using a similar subtotal formula and similar averageif(), but averaging out the occurrences instead of the actual [score] data.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Have added an explanation. Can you clarify your latest request by adding some desired results to your post?

Comment: Jos, Thank you for everything thus far. I have updated my question with one final request. I appreciate you taking the time to explain everything to me

Answer (score 0):

So, I would use averageifs().

=averageifs(B:B,B:B,">=1",A:A,"A")

is one example, note I have added the control of Type A in the example.

See:
[image]